# ng-if inside ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I am generating a dynamic form in AngularJS:

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in myData" class='repeater'>
    <div ng-if="choice.type === 'dropdown'" ng-init="count = 0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p>choose</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.value for item in mydatedropdown[count]"> </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{count += 1}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I was unable to increment the value of count and assign it to `mydatedropdown[]`. I am new to AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

you could try changing your ng-repeat to `<div ng-repeat="(index, choice) in myData" class='repeater'>` and use `index` in `mydatedropdown`

```
<div ng-repeat="(index, choice) in myData" class='repeater'>
    <div ng-if="choice.type === 'dropdown'" ng-init="count = 0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p>choose</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.value for item in mydatedropdown[index]"> </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```